# Can .net core app have some APIs with client credentials flow and others with Open ID connect

Tags: .net-core, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

Currently .Net Core app has APIs with OpenID Connect configured. It gets user token and validates.

Now have a requirement to implement client credential flow for 2 APIs leaving rest with OpenID connect. These two APIs are triggered by another backend system. By providing client id,secret and grant type = client credentials , back end system is able to invoke these two APIs. But problem is it can also invoke other APIs which i don't want.

Looking for a way to achieve this in .Net Core. Please advise

Comment: An access token can only for one resource/API. Why are you saying it can invoke multiple APIs. Can you provide more details?

Comment: Our .Net app has multiple API endpoints. We have Azure App registration for the .Net app with client id and secret.  So using client id , secret , grant type=client credentials caller is able to access all APIs with in .Net app using token; whereas we want client credentials to be enabled just for 2 APIs & rest should be through OpenID only. Please let me know if this clarifies your question

Comment: For APIs, do you mean multiple API endpoints under a resource?

Comment: Client credentials flow is for Application permission (no user) while OpenID Connect protocol is for Delegated permission (require signed-in user). So I don't think these two kinds of permissions will be included in the access token at the same time. When you use Client credentials flow, the delegated permissions used for OpenID Connect protocol won't be included in the access token. It should not be able to invoke other API endpoints which require delegated permissions. Share your permissions configured in Azure AD app.

Comment: @AllenWu Thanks.  Say below API end points in .Net. Please share if there is a way to annotate Client credential for API1 and OpenID for API2. 

public class sample : ApiController{
  
 public IList < Employee > API1()  
        {  
            //Return list of all employees  
            return employees;  
        } 
    public IList < Employee > API2()  
        {  
            //Return list of all employees  
            return employees;  
        }  
}

Comment: What is the difficulty here? As I suggested before, when you implement client credential flow for API1, the access token only includes the application permission rather than delegated permission. But API2 needs delegated permission. You can control the permission in code easily to decide which API it can call.

Comment: I don't know how to implement client credential for API1 and delegated for API2. Right i have implemented as follows for a controller (applies to all APIs). Looking for help which schemas to use for OpenID vs Delegated at API level. I can call APIs in controller with both type of tokens now. 

[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = AuthSchemes)]
   private const string AuthSchemes =
   CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme + "," +
   OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme + "," + JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

Comment: I think i might have to check grant_type in each API like grant_type=client_credentials for API1 and grant_type=Open ID for API2 , throw error if expected grant_type is not sent in the token

https://blog.elmah.io/how-to-secure-asp-net-core-with-oauth-and-json-web-tokens/

Comment: Delegated permission is verified as `scope`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-verification-scope-app-roles#verify-scopes-in-apis-called-on-behalf-of-users.   Application permission is verified as `app roles`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-verification-scope-app-roles#verify-app-roles-in-apis-called-by-daemon-apps. You need to verify the permission. I think this method is more suitable.

Comment: @AllenWu - This is exactly i am looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to know that. I'll add an answer so that this issue can be treated as closed. You can mark it as answered. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Mohan, how did you resolve this? I am facing the same issue, in my startup.cs file In configure services method I used open id connect authentication scheme, and I m not sure how to implement jwt bearer token for other apis which is going to be accessed by some external system

Comment: Hi Amol - Added this to our backlog , yet to be implemented to access certain APIs with client credentials only(Other system consumer) and other APIs with "on behalf of users" (OpenID).  Currently API accepts both type and not checking scope/claims. In start up , added all .AddCookie() .AddOpenIdConnect , .AddJwtBearer in AddAuthentication. In API controller " [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = AuthSchemes)]"  where AuthSchemes = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme + "," +       OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme + "," + JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you implement client credential flow, the access token will include the [Application permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-registration#exposing-application-permissions-app-roles).

If you implement OpenID Connect flow, the access token will include the [Delegated permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-registration#exposing-delegated-permissions-scopes).

In order to control which API the client app can access, you need to verify the permission.

You can learn more configuration from how to [verify Application permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-verification-scope-app-roles#verify-app-roles-in-apis-called-by-daemon-apps) and [verify Delegated permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-verification-scope-app-roles#verify-scopes-in-apis-called-on-behalf-of-users).